# This might be the worst book of mine that

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is there anything wrong about the following sentence?

This might be the worst document of mine (i.e. written by me) that you have ever read (or "that you are going to read"?).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 'This might be the worst document of mine that you will ever read' sounds more natural.

Comment: The sentence is fine, your title is not.